# Update data in elasticsearch from csv

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of indices A,B,C,D containing large amounts of data per each let's say 50 million records per index and the record contains data as follows:

```
user: amine, age: 22, state: Michigan
```

and I want to create a new index E and bulk new data into it from a csv file. What I hope for is that if a user from E already exists in one of the other indices but with different information for example:

```
user: amine, age: 25, state: California
```

I want the user amine to be updated in all other indices with the new data.
I tried pulling all the data processing it and re-ingesting it but the process took so long.

Comment: Are A-D using `user` as document id? Also, are you using bulk inserts/updates?

Comment: no they use separate ids and yes I am using bulk inserts

Comment: If you use `user` as doc ID (or have doc IDs in CSV) you can update all indices in a single bulk. Also, make sure to [tune your cluster for indexing speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html).